# Visual studio does not show content of files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2022

[image]

Picture says it all, it should currently be showing a file but as you can see its having issues drawing the content of the file.

I have unloaded all addons and restart visual studio.

If it matters the previous project was a VS 2k8.

**New Info:**

If i wait a good 5min ( I have a Quad core I7 with 6gb ram,  295gtx. VS is running from a SSD).

It will load the text, but I'm unable to "edit", as it will have loaded some document (`.cs`) but when i select the one i want to edit it not really open that file.

It can best be described as visual studio having a 5min lag.

Comment: Huh?  No files are open - what exactly are you expecting to see?

Comment: Files are open, its just unable to draw the content of file viewer

Comment: Have you tried non-CS files?  Maybe add a .txt file to the project and see if that opens.

Comment: Same bug with text files. Gonna check if its font related

Comment: Added new info. Change font and have the same issue

Comment: So you've got an i7 with 6GB RAM and SSD - I'd say your computer is too good for Visual Studio.  I'm jealous.

Comment: Just had similar issue in vs2015 when open old vs2012 solution. After I restarted the vs all being good then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was created by [mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/) 1.2.x, but is fixed in the snapshot versions of 1.3.x. YOu can likely get simular bugs by other software that does DirectX overlay.

Answer (score 2):

I had this precise bug.  I would open files from the solution explorer but the editor window would either not appear, only 1-2 lines of 100+ line files would display, or the file would display but I could not scroll or otherwise edit the file.  Some parts of VS were working, i.e. little tooltips would appear if I moused over the right part of the (invisible) text but I obviously couldn't do much in this state.

I have a lot of VS stuff installed so I thought it was some sort of plugin or extension that was causing things to go screwy.  These installed items include:

- Visual Studio 2010 10.0.30319.1
- ReSharper 5.1.3000.12 (JetBrains)
- DevExpress DXCore 10.1.5 (free community edition)
- DX Source Outliner (reason for DXCore, from sbohlen)
- Tabs Studio 2.0.6 (www.tabsstudio.com)
- Productivity Power Tools 10.0.11019.3 (Microsoft)
- Snippet Designer 1.3.0 (Matt Manela)

I solved it (2/18/2011) by Tools... Extension Manager... disabling the Productivity Power Tools and Snippet Designer.  No idea what was going on but this fixed it for me and I was back to work.  Probably something in the system drawing and/or display options.

**EDIT**

The issue continues.  Unfortunately it is intermittent and I have not be able to reproduce it reliably.  Now the suspects are the BugShooting and CaptureWiz screen capture tools.  I've had the behavior show up and then disappear in and around the time of logging bugs with them.

**2nd EDIT**

The issue continually continues.  I have not yet been able to determine the cause but usually quitting VS and restarting resolves the issue(s).  Other parts of the behavior includes the menu options (File, Edit, View, etc.) not operating properly as they show only the highlight but not the actual menu items.  The solution will build and run just fine, but things still won't show up properly.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue whereby VS2012 was telling me that I had active (open) files, but the text editor was not displaying them. Clicking on the file(s) in the solution explorer seemingly did nothing. Alt + Tab just cycled through the open files, but still, nothing rendered on screen.

I solved it by clicking on the "WINDOW" menu item and then"Close All Documents". Visual Studio then behaved as expected and opened (and rendered) the files correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Visual Studio 2012. It was fixed by running a repair of Visual Studio 2012 via Add/ Remove Programs.

The following had no effect:

- Closing and reopening a solution
- Opening different file types
- Restarting Visual Studio
- Adding and removing plugins
- Resetting options via the 'Reset all Settings' option in Visual Studio's 'Import and Export Settings'
- Rebooting windows

Comment: I was seeing this issue in Visual Studio Code and posted a question at: https://superuser.com/questions/1628804/why-does-visual-studio-code-vsc-display-nothing-when-i-open-a-folder-containin

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Visual Studio 2013. Problem was: extension "Regex Tester". I had to uninstall this extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in Visual Studio 2022, and based on others answer it seems problem come from Visual Studio Extensions
I encountered this problem problem when  disable my Resharper 2023.1.2
after re-enable Resharper extension, problem solved!